# Make certain user inputs not mandatory/default values

Tags: java

I have a build() method that creates a Booking from a user's input. Currently it has that each variable must be added. How do I make certain variables not mandatory? i.e. accept a blank value?

```
public static Booking build() throws BuilderException {
    if (date == null)
        throw new BuilderException("Valid date not found");

    if (hours < MINHOURS)
        throw new BuilderException("Minimum hours for booking is " + MINHOURS);

    if (attendance < MINATT)
        throw new BuilderException("Minimum headcount is " + MINATT);

    if (location == null)
        throw new BuilderException("Valid location not found");

    if (building == null)
        throw new BuilderException("Valid building not found");

    if (emailAddress == null)
        throw new BuilderException("Valid email address not found");

    if (contactNumber == null)
        throw new BuilderException("Valid contact number not found");

    return new Booking(date, hours, attendance, location, building, emailAddress, contactNumber);
}
```

So for example I want to keep contactNumber mandatory, but if location/building is left blank then that's ok. Thanks

Comment: set a default value?

Comment: @notyou No not a default value, just if the user hasn't entered a value, it can accept null

Comment: then set them all initially as `null` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can simply remove the lines with null checks for the parameters you want to make optional. Then they will just be null, and that null will be passed to the constructor. Well, this will work unless there's also something in the constructor code that will prevent null values from being used.

Answer (score 0):

For example, let assume that we have a method with 2 arguments: `x` and `y`. The `x` is required and `y` is optional.

Then we can write:

```
int myMethod(int x, int y){
    // ... code
}

int myMethod(int x){
    int defaultY = 5; // for example 5
    return myMethod(x, defaultY);
}
```

Now ya can call `myMethod` with y like this:   `myMethod(1, 2);`

but ya can also withouth y:
`myMethod(1);`. It will work as: `myMethod(1, 5);`

Comment: @W W So for the code I posted above, is there no code I can add to the if (location) .. statement that will make it non-mandatory?

Comment: Do the same as I did in the example. Make 2 `Booking` constructors. 1 with  `location` in arguments and 1 without.